# dbus: difference between system bus and session bus

Tags: dbus

I do not understand the difference between DBus *system* bus and *session* bus. For example, when I run the command

```
$ dbus-daemon --<session/system> --print-address --fork
```

it seems to me that the situation is as follows (please correct me if and where I am wrong):

- There is no principle difference between these buses. This magical word in options is only a refence to the file name in `/usr/share/dbus-1/`. If we start `dbus-daemon` with the option `--session` then settings from `/usr/share/dbus-1/session.conf` are used, and for `--system` settings from `/usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf` are used. But this is a difference only in settings...
- There is no difference in using these buses. For both we need to use `--print-address` when starting the daemon and this address has to be passed somehow to all programs, which are going to use DBus. The system bus seems to not have a special pre-defined address, that is known to all clients.

If the statements above are true, then what is the difference between these types of DBus? Is it like some agreement, that the word `system` will be used for one group of communications and the word `session` will be used for some other group of communications? We can definitely start several buses by calling several times

```
$ ADDRESS1=$(dbus-daemon --session --print-address --fork)
$ ADDRESS2=$(dbus-daemon --session --print-address --fork)
...
```

And then use several independent session buses. Can we do the same for system bus?

Sorry for so many questions...

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? There are two buses, a session bus for each user login session and a single system bus that provides access to system services. These are typically already running `ps -ef | grep dbus` and you use the `name`  (can be found with `busctl --system list` or `busctl --user list`) to interact with them. Or create your own name if publishing to one of the buses.

Comment: @ukBaz I am trying to understand what it is and how it works. And no, it is not a god given service, which runs everywhere. I have a dockerized system, where there is no `dbus-daemon` running. I am starting it myself and want to know what the difference is between starting a system bus daemon or a session bus daemon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one system bus, and it runs as a system-level service. System-wide services are accessible on it.

There are zero or more session buses, one for each user session. They run as the user, and do not have elevated privileges. The user’s applications are accessible on each of them (to other applications within that user session).

Comment: What does that mean for users of dbus? Is there any difference for client programs if they talk to each other using session bus or system bus?

Comment: Client programs don’t generally talk to each other using D-Bus. Clients talk to services. So the split in buses means that clients need to connect to the right bus for the service they want to talk to. Services need to be registered on the right bus depending on whether they provide system-level functionality (always available if the computer is turned on, such as Bluetooth handling) or session level functionality (only available within a user’s session, such as desktop notification support).

Comment: sorry, I meant the service registering its name on the DBus. It is not completely true that session bus is only for a user. My docker image of a system does not have any `dbus-daemon` running after the system start. I am starting `dbus-daemon` manually under `root` and it is my choice whether to start it as `--session` or `--system`. And then I manually start a service, written using `sdbus-c++`, which then talks to clients, written also using `sdbus-c++`. And I am trying to understand what the difference will be if I start `dbus-daemon` as system or session. May be there is no difference?

Comment: Sure, you can configure and run dbus-daemon how you like. The spec defines a few well-known bus configurations, of which session and system are two: https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-bus-types

Running with `--session` or `--system` will pick which of the default configuration files `dbus-daemon` uses, as you noted in the OP.

Comment: That was the question: I was asking for an explanation of how these two well-known bus configurations differ from each other. An explanation with a little bit more details than the standard "system is for system services, session is for other services".

Comment: I think I’ve said everything which differentiates the system and session buses. There’s really not that much to it. System *is* for system services, and the zero or more session buses *are* for user session services. What more were you expecting?